# What happens when you change the Account currency of an Account from EUR to GBP?

Tags: account, multi-currency, currency, currencyisocode

What happens when you change the Account currency of an Account from EUR to GBP?

Does making any changes to the standard currency field impact on any other areas?

Answer (score 2):

If you change the Currency field to other currency value(Like from Euro to GBP) if there is any amount value of the record you have to adjust that value to corresponding currency. Because if you change the currency type salesforce wont convert the value in the amount to corresponding values.

Also there will be mismatch between the related records currency(Opportunity) and parent record currency(Account). If there are any roll up calculations on it this may impact.